# Make a fake post request?

Tags: php, post, request

i was making a website in php and i am using forms and post requests for many things. In order to test and debug the GET requests i used a chrome extension called `postman`. I noticed that this extension has also `POST` requests. What would happen if for example make a post request on facebook with my facebook password? The credentials would be correct and also the request will hit the correct target but again what would happen? Can i just make post requests to any website like that?

Comment: Why don't you try and see... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can POST to any website you'd like. Facebook is a bit more difficult due to session cookies and their authentication process, but give it a try and see how it works out for you.

+points for exploring how HTTP works

Answer (score 1):

Websites **should** treat POST input as user input and as such should validate and sterilize it as needed, nothing should prevent you from attempting such a thing but the complexity of the request and the legal standpoint of faking/automating requests to a site without informing them (I am not a lawyer).
If you want to attempt such a thing while being a good "internet citizen" I'd recommend you to take the following precautions:

1. Set a user agent different than the normal web browser.
2. Do not flood websites with attempts.
3. Do not use a profile you are using in day to day life, as it may be blocked for spam or by the IDS.
4. Look up if there are test/development flags you can set to let the website know you are testing/developing.